# is the zoom factor for builtInTripleCamera's .5 zoom 1.0?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturedevice

I'm working on a camera app and I currently don't have a device with a triple camera (so I cannot test). When an app initially configures a camera, I want the camera setting with no zoom in and out until the user starts pinching in or out (then starts zooming in or out).

In the [video zoom factor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624611-videozoomfactor) documentation, it says

> Allowed values range from 1.0 (full field of view) to the value of the active format’s videoMaxZoomFactor property.

So, when the triple camera uses its 2x zoom out, that time the video zoom factor is 1.0?
and if it doesn't use any zoom functionality, the zoom factor becomes 2.0 (like the double of the 2x zoom out's zoom factor)?

Therefore, when configuring the camera with no zoom or out, do I need to set 2.0 for zoom factor only when using the triple camera?

```
var videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

init() {
    getBestDevice()
    setInitialZoomFactor(for: self.videoDevice)
}

let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInTripleCamera, .builtInDualWideCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)

func getBestDevice() {
    let devices = discoverySession.devices
    guard !devices.isEmpty else { fatalError("Missing capture devices.")}
    videoDevice = devices.first
}

func setInitialZoomFactor(for device: AVCaptureDevice?) {
    guard let device = device else { return }
    
    do {
        try videoDevice.lockForConfiguration()
        
        if videoDevice.deviceType == .builtInTripleCamera {
            videoDevice.videoZoomFactor = 2.0
        } else {
            videoDevice.videoZoomFactor = 1.0
        }
      
        videoDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("got error")
    }
}
```